# Sound sample attachement feature request

Tags: feature-request

As it already exists for pictures, is it possible to implement a specific attachement feature for music files as well?

Currently, to share music samples, we need to add the link manually using many third websites like SoundCloud, Dropbox, etc. However we don't do that for pictures. In addition, if there are some changes made on the third party side (like a deletion by mistake), that means the link on the [Sound Design](http://sound.stackexchange.com) side could be broken and therefore the given QA would be no longer helpful.

We could imagine something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unless things have changed, I believe SE has a similar partnership with SoundCloud as they do with Imgur.  It should also auto-format soundcloud links in to players.  I do know that they did some SoundCloud specific stuff a while ago.

Comment: Yes, I noticed some samples are embed as a SoundCloud frame. That said, even if there is a partnership to do that, the user has still to upload himself the sample on a SoundCloud account (and being aware of secret/private links not to pollute his public uploads list), copy the generated link, and paste it in SE. In addition as the user won't probably know this partnership he could still use another hosting provider instead of SoundCloud.